# Numpy Number Patterns

Tags: arrays, numpy

Is there a function in Numpy that allows you to take 4 records at a time and see where they match with a second dataset? Once there is a match move to the next 4 records of the first data set.  It wont always be every 4 records, but i am using this as an example.

```
So if dataset one had - 1,5,7,8,10,12,6,1,3,6,8,9

And the second dataset had - 1,5,7,8,11,15,6,1,3,6,10,6

My result will be:  1,5,7,8, 6,1,3,6
```

**POST EDIT:**
My second example datasets:

```
 import numpy as np

 a =np.array([15,15,0,0,10,10,0,0,2,1,8,8,42,2,4,4,3,1,1,3,5,6,0,9,47,1,1,7,7,0,0,45,12,17,45])

 b = np.array ([6,0,0,15,15,0,0,10,10,0,0,2,1,8,8,42,2,4,4,3,3,4,6,0,9,47,1,1,7,7,0,0,45,12,16,1,9,3,30])
```

Here's another snapshot of an example:
[image]

Thank you in advance for looking at my question!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: for the more difficult and more interesting alignment problem it is probably best not to reinvent the wheel but to rely on python's `difflib`:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
import numpy as np

k=4

a = np.array([15,15,0,0,10,10,0,0,2,1,8,8,42,2,4,4,3,1,1,3,5,6,0,9,47,1,1,7,7,0,0,45,12,17,45])

b = np.array ([6,0,0,15,15,0,0,10,10,0,0,2,1,8,8,42,2,4,4,3,3,4,6,0,9,47,1,1,7,7,0,0,45,12,16,1,9,3,30])

sm = SequenceMatcher(a=a, b=b)
matches = sm.get_matching_blocks()
matches = [m for m in matches if m.size >= k]
# [Match(a=0, b=3, size=17), Match(a=21, b=22, size=12)]
consensus = [a[m.a:m.a+m.size] for m in matches]
# [array([15, 15,  0,  0, 10, 10,  0,  0,  2,  1,  8,  8, 42,  2,  4,  4,  3]), array([ 6,  0,  9, 47,  1,  1,  7,  7,  0,  0, 45, 12])]
consfour = [a[m.a:m.a + m.size // k * k] for m in matches]
# [array([15, 15,  0,  0, 10, 10,  0,  0,  2,  1,  8,  8, 42,  2,  4,  4]), array([ 6,  0,  9, 47,  1,  1,  7,  7,  0,  0, 45, 12])]
summary = [np.c_[np.add.outer(np.arange(m.size // k * k), (m.a, m.b)), c]
           for m, c in zip(matches, consfour)]
merge = np.concatenate(summary, axis=0)
```

Below is my original solution assuming already aligned and same-length arrays:

Here is a hybrid solution using `numpy` to find consecutive matches and cutting them out and then list comp to apply length constraints:

```
import numpy as np

d1 = np.array([7,1,5,7,8,0,6,9,0,10,12,6,1,3,6,8,9])
d2 = np.array([8,1,5,7,8,0,6,9,0,11,15,6,1,3,6,10,6])

k = 4

# find matches
m = d1 == d2

# find switches between match, no match
sw = np.where(m[:-1] != m[1:])[0] + 1

# split
mnm = np.split(d1, sw)

# select matches
ones_ = mnm[1-m[0]::2]

# apply length constraint
res = [blck[i:i+k] for blck in ones_ for i in range(len(blck)-k+1)]
# [array([1, 5, 7, 8]), array([5, 7, 8, 0]), array([7, 8, 0, 6]), array([8, 0, 6, 9]), array([0, 6, 9, 0]), array([6, 1, 3, 6])]
res_no_ovlp = [blck[k*i:k*i+k] for blck in ones_ for i in range(len(blck)//k)]
# [array([1, 5, 7, 8]), array([0, 6, 9, 0]), array([6, 1, 3, 6])]
```

Comment: Hi @Paul sorry for the late reply, but I received a msg that the question wasn't posted.  I tried your solution with a larger dataset, and it didn't work.  I posted an image of an more detailed example.  My actual datasets range around 4k records.  Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: I tried it with data set example that I added in the post-- I typed out the array, to help out on the typing  :-)  and I got error:  sw = np.where(m[:-1] != m[1:])[0] + 1

TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable

Comment: m is a bool not an array

Comment: both of d1 and d2 are arrays.  sorry, but I just started numpy so I'm trying to figure things out as I go.  thanks again.

Comment: @yanci, ok the problem seems to be that your `a` and `b` have different lengths. (35 and 39). I thought that wasn't allowed. If it is, you'd have to better explain by which rules your groups of four can be aligned to match them.

Comment: the lengths can vary.  in the case that a is larger than b, then the left over become non-matches.  in the image above I show how the records fall off as 'non-match'.  the datasets need to be aligned based on the number column.  those that do not have a match, are not aligned.  I'm trying to see if I can do it with an array comparison....I won't be pretty.  If I can get it soon, I will re-post my code.

Comment: @ Paul, I tried using the code by making both lines 35 and m did not yield the correct true/false results.

Comment: Here's another thing that I was trying.  Closest match, by using out=pd.merge_asof(df1,df2,on='number',direction='nearest'), but I am not having any luck, because it calls for the keys to be sorted.  if, they are sorted, then the order is lost.  Anyway, thanks for trying!

Comment: thank you for working on it!  I think I understand it, but do you mind explaining it?  also, do you know if it is possible to retrieve the position of both of these and then make an array of 3 columns, Position 1, Position 2, Matching Number.  for example: for the first match of 15 to produce 0,3,15.  0 being position of first array, 3 being position of second array, and 15 the matching number.  I really appreciate all your help!

Comment: @yanci Could you pls check whether the `summary` and `merge` objects in the modified code do what you want? Re explanation. I don't know what to explain since I'm essentially not doing anything. All the heavy lifting is done by `difflib`. So the call to `SequenceMatcher` creates a SequenceMatcher object and provides it with the data. The we call the `.get_matching_blocks` method and the library finds all matches for us. You can play with `matches` to see how they are represented. All that's left for us to do is filter out short matches and make sure we only keep multiples of four.

Comment: @ Paul, I see now.  I didn't understand what the matches array was displaying.  Sorry...takes me a minute.  This will work perfectly!!  I am going to try it on a larger dataset.  Thanks again, I really appreciate it!

Comment: @ Paul, Last question....when you get a chance, the line sm = SequenceMatcher (a=a, b=b)  -->  what does this mean?  I was looking at examples and they always reference 3 parameters.  Also, if I add a column to my array, like an ID, what would be by SequenceMatcher parameter?

Comment: @yanci `SequenceMatcher` is a `class`. (If you don't know what a class is you'll have to read up on it; very briefly a class is a collection of data that knows how to work with them; in our case it stores `a` and `b` and it has the `get_matching_blocks` method to process them.) Syntactically, a class name followed by parentheses, calls the class constructor, i.e. creates an instance of the class. In the docs you can see that all arguments to the constructor are keyword arguments with a default. Since we are happy with the default for the first argument, we skip it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use matrix masking like,

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import dia_matrix
a = np.array([1,5,7,8,10,12,6,1,3,6,8,9])
b = np.array([1,5,7,8,11,15,6,1,3,6,10,6])
mask = dia_matrix((np.ones((1, a.size)).repeat(4, axis=0), np.arange(4)),
                  shape=(a.size, b.size), dtype=np.int)
print(mask.toarray())
matches = a[mask.T.dot(mask.dot(a == b) == 4).astype(np.bool)]
print(matches)
```

This will output,

```
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
[1 5 7 8 6 1 3 6]
```

You can think about how the matrix multiplication works to get this result.

### Scaling

For scaling, I tested with 1e3, 1e5, and 1e7 elements and got,

```
1e3 - 0.019184964010491967
1e5 - 0.4330314120161347
1e7 - 144.54082221200224
```

See the [gist](https://gist.github.com/aidan-plenert-macdonald/f00e4fbcde3cad68cedb6ff116af6f5d). Not sure why such a hard jump at 1e7 elements.

Comment: That's clever, but does it require that the two lists are the same lenght?

Comment: Clever, indeed, but maybe use a sparse matrix, so it doesn't become O(n^2)?

Comment: Hi @aidan.plenert.macdonald,   I tried your solution with a larger dataset, and I received a too many indices for array error. I posted an image of a more detailed example. My actual datasets range around 4k records. Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: @innisfree As currently written, yes, but the actual masking trick doesn't require same length. I'm updating it now, but I think the OP only cared about same length lists.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Changed to sparse. Actually makes the code more intuitive.

Comment: @yanci I put some benchmarks in my post. Not entirely sure what your problem is. It worked fine for me. Sounds like something was wrong on your side. I'd post another question for that particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is an exercise is list comprehension. We have the data

```
data = [1,5,7,8,10,12,6,1,3,6,8,9]
search_data = [1,5,7,8,11,15,6,1,3,6,10,6]
```

First we can chunk the original data into blocks of length n

```
n = 4
chunks = [data[i:i + n] for i in range(len(data) - n + 1)]
search_chunks = [search_data[i:i + n] for i in range(len(search_data) - n + 1)]
```

Now we must select chunks from the first list that appear in the second list

```
hits = [c for c in chunks if c in search_chunks]
print hits
# [[1, 5, 7, 8], [6, 1, 3, 6]]
```

This may not be the optimal solution for long lists. It may improve performance to consider sets, if there are likely to repeated chunks

```
chunks = set(tuple(data[i:i + n]) for i in range(len(data) - n + 1))
search_chunks = set(tuple(search_data[i:i + n]) for i in range(len(search_data) - n + 1))
```

This can be quite competitive with above numpy solution, e.g.

```
import numpy as np
import time

# Generate data

len_ = 10000
max_ = 10
data = map(int, np.random.rand(len_) * max_)
search_data = map(int, np.random.rand(len_) * max_)

# Time list comprehension

start = time.time()

n = 4
chunks = set(tuple(data[i:i + n]) for i in range(len(data) - n + 1))
search_chunks = set(tuple(search_data[i:i + n]) for i in range(len(search_data) - n + 1))
hits = [c for c in chunks if c in search_chunks]

print time.time() - start

# Time numpy

a = np.array(data)
b = np.array(search_data)
mask = 1 * (np.abs(np.arange(a.size).reshape((-1, 1)) - np.arange(a.size) - 0.5) < 2)

start = time.time()

matches = a[mask.T.dot(mask.dot(a == b) == 4).astype(np.bool)]

print time.time() - start
```

It's typically faster here, but it depends on number of repeated chunks etc.